# Other views size change to zero automatically in autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, autolayout

I am very new in auto layout and storyboard too. I am started learning both but now I found a problem and can't solve it by google. Below is my view hierarchy.

[image]

and below is my Interface Builder Document

[image]

Now my problem is when I am trying to resize an UIView using mouse all others UIView's rect become zero (0 0, 0 0). I am doing it in swift but I found the same in objective-C too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AutoLayout then you have to actually **use** AutoLayout.

Ticking "Use Auto Layout" is the first part.

You need to add constraints to the views to define the sizes of them.

Take a look at this [Ray Wenderlich AutoLayout tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).

Comment: Thanx for reply but actually I was started learning from the link you give. You can understand this by my layout design.

Comment: Then just add the constraints. Like I said, if you're using AutoLayout then use AutoLayout.

Comment: Thank you bro. Now I understood that before adding or modifying any other control first I have to add constraints to existing views. :) Thanks a lot.